# Cannot use 'null' as class name as it is reserved Concrete 5.7

Tags: php, zend-framework, concrete5

i upgraded my Concrete 5.7 website from php 5.6.x to 7.0.4 and get the folowing error

```
 {"error":{"type":"Whoops\\Exception\\ErrorException","message":"Cannot use 'Null' as class name as it is reserved","file":"\/usr\/share\/nginx\/html\/concrete\/vendor\/zendframework\/zend-queue\/library\/ZendQueue\/Adapter\/Null.php","line":24,"trace":[{"file":"\/usr\/share\/nginx\/html\/concrete\/vendor\/zendframework\/zend-queue\/library\/ZendQueue\/Adapter\/Null.php","line":24,"function":null,"class":null,"args":[]}]},"errors":["Cannot use 'Null' as class name as it is reserved"]}
```

the function that trigger this is a concrete 5 function itself.

What can i do to fix this?

PHP 7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Rename the class.

Comment: This is why you should use a proper IDE when you write code. It would have told you that Null is a reserved word in PHP. It has nothing to do with Concrete 5.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Eriksson the stuff that makes this error is in the Concrete5 base folder i didnt change anything there. if it would be my class i just would rename it like Dagon said
"file":"\/usr\/share\/nginx\/html\/concrete\/vendor\/zendframework\/zend-queue\/library\/ZendQueue\/Adapter\/Null.php"

Comment: That's because it got reserved in PHP 7, while it was allowed in PHP 5.6.

Comment: Looks like the class is actually `\ZendQueue\Adapter\Null` : https://github.com/zendframework/ZendQueue/blob/master/library/ZendQueue/Adapter/Null.php - part of ZF2

Comment: @CD001 - Yepp... and it's a known compatibility issue: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendQueue/issues/25

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - heh, you'd think Zend (the PHP people) would know what they're doing... they must have had an inkling naming a class `Null` was a probably a bad idea.

Comment: @CD001 - You would think so. Concrete 5 itself is using `Object` as class name. That should still work in PHP 7 but it is a "soft reserved"-word (meaning that it will stop working in an upcoming PHP release). Seems like Concrete 5 is a bad choice if you want to run PHP 7...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to upgrade your concrete5 installation to a current version.